# Unsubscribe after observable 'completes'

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

I am receiving data from firebase through RxJS via the query below:

```
getAppliedLocalTags() {
    this.tagSub = this.pageService
      .getTagsOnPage(this.workspaceId, this.currentPage.id)
      .pipe(
        switchMap((references) => from(references)),
        mergeMap((ref) => this.afs.doc(ref).snapshotChanges()),
        map((actions) => actions.payload.data()),
        scan((allTagData, tagData) => [...allTagData, tagData], [])
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.appliedTags = data;
      });
    // STOP THE SUB ONCE WE GET THE TAGS
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("un-subbed from tags");
      this.tagSub.unsubscribe();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

When the subscription comes in, `this.appliedTags` gets populated with all of the 'tags' coming from the database.

In this case, I only want the values once. After I get all values, I unsubscribe, but the best method that I have at the moment for doing this is by using `setTimeout(() => {}, 2000),` which is not ideal as the time will vary based on network, number of tags, etc..

Unfortunately, I have yet to find a solution that unsubscribes from the data stream after an observable has 'completed.'

Is there a way to unsubscribe after the observable 'completes,' or stops emitting values?

Thank you!!

Comment: When observable is complete - all subs are gone.

Comment: `take(10)` will unsubscribe after 10 emissions

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove `take(10)`, as the number of tags will vary.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solve in two ways :

**Promise way:**

```
getAppliedLocalTags() {
    this.tagSub = this.pageService
      .getTagsOnPage(this.workspaceId, this.currentPage.id)
    .pipe(
        switchMap((references) => from(references)),
        mergeMap((ref) => this.afs.doc(ref).snapshotChanges()),
        map((actions) => actions.payload.data()),
        scan((allTagData, tagData) => [...allTagData, tagData], [])
      )
    .toPromise().then((data) => {
            this.appliedTags = data;
        }).catch(err => {
        // handle error
    });
}
```

Another way is use ***take*** operator:

```
getAppliedLocalTags() {
    this.tagSub = this.pageService
      .getTagsOnPage(this.workspaceId, this.currentPage.id)
      .pipe(
        switchMap((references) => from(references)),
        mergeMap((ref) => this.afs.doc(ref).snapshotChanges()),
        map((actions) => actions.payload.data()),
        scan((allTagData, tagData) => [...allTagData, tagData], []),
        take(1) // This will emit only once then..
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.appliedTags = data;
      });
  }
```

Comment: I tried both, and both did not return anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @MasonSecky-Koebel That means in initial call you are not getting anything! Try removing take operator and replace with distinctUntilChanged() this will basically emit only when there is a data change in the stream.

Comment: The initial call gets anywhere from 0 -> n 'tag' documents. Using `take(1)` limits me to just one. It _did_ emit something, but only 1 tag in an example where 3 are present (and up to n possible).

`toPromise` did not work in this case, I believe, because this is a data stream.

One thought I had (and am working on) was getting the size of the `references` array and using `take(numOfRefs)`, as this would limit the emissions to the number of tags.